# How RTLCSS Framework works in WebEssentials in Visual Studio 2017.? How to integrate the RLCSS framework in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

I'm starting a new project in .NET Framework from scratch and I'm new to this framework.

I would like to know how we will integrate RTLCSS framework for Web Essentials in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm starting a .NET MVC Web application and I'm using the SCSS for the stylesheet. When I searched I found that Web Essentials is required for SCSS conversion and minification. I would like to generate the rtl.css for all the corresponding stylesheet and RTLCSS framework will provide for my requirement. Could you please help me to find out the solution.

The previous version of the Web Essentials in Visual Studio 2015 works fine for the RTL generation and I found the configuration settings in **WebEssentials-Settings.json** file.

```
{
   ....
   ....
   "Css" : {
       ....
       ....
       "RtlCss":true,
   }

}
```

Below is the code in **WebEssentials-Settings.json** file

```js
{  
   "BrowserLink":{  
      "CssIgnorePatterns":"bootstrap*; reset.css; normalize.css; jquery*; toastr*; foundation*; animate*; inuit*; elements*; ratchet*; hint*; flat-ui*; 960*; skeleton*",
      "EnableMenu":true,
      "EnablePixelPushing":false,
      "ShowMenu":false
   },
   "CodeGen":{  
      "AddTypeScriptReferencePath":true,
      "CamelCaseEnumerationValues":false,
      "CamelCasePropertyNames":true,
      "CamelCaseTypeNames":false
   },
   "CoffeeScript":{  
      "CompileOnBuild":false,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "GenerateSourceMaps":true,
      "LintOnBuild":false,
      "LintOnSave":true,
      "LintResultLocation":"Message",
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements":true,
      "ShowPreviewPane":true,
      "WrapClosure":true
   },
   "Css":{  
      "AdjustRelativePaths":true,
      "AutoMinify":true,
      "Autoprefix":false,
      "AutoprefixerBrowsers":null,
      "GenerateRtlSourceMaps":true,
      "GzipMinifiedFiles":false,
      "MakeMinified":true,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "RtlCss":true,
      "RunOnBuild":false,
      "ShowBrowserTooltip":true,
      "ShowInitialInherit":false,
      "ShowUnsupported":true,
      "SyncBase64ImageValues":true,
      "SyncVendorValues":true,
      "ValidateEmbedImages":true,
      "ValidateStarSelector":true,
      "ValidateVendorSpecifics":true,
      "ValidateZeroUnit":true,
      "ValidationLocation":"Messages"
   },
   "General":{  
      "AllMessagesToOutputWindow":false,
      "KeepImportantComments":true,
      "ShowWEIgnoreLogs":true,
      "SvgPreviewPane":true
   },
   "Handlebars":{  
      "CompileOnBuild":false,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null
   },
   "Html":{  
      "AttributeQuotesRemovalMode":"KeepQuotes",
      "AutoMinify":false,
      "CustomAngularDirectiveList":null,
      "EnableAngularValidation":true,
      "EnableBootstrapValidation":true,
      "EnableEnterFormat":true,
      "EnableFoundationValidation":true,
      "EnableMicrodataValidation":true,
      "GzipMinifiedFiles":false,
      "ImageDropFormats":[  
         {  
            "HtmlFormat":"<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" />",
            "Name":"Simple Image Tag"
         },
         {  
            "HtmlFormat":"<div><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" /></div>",
            "Name":"Enclosed in Div"
         },
         {  
            "HtmlFormat":"<li id=\"item_{1}\"><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" /></li>",
            "Name":"Enclosed as List Item"
         },
         {  
            "HtmlFormat":"<div style=\"background-image=url('{0}')\"></div>",
            "Name":"Inline CSS"
         }
      ],
      "MakeMinified":true,
      "MinifyAngularBindingExpressions":false,
      "MinifyKnockoutBindingExpressions":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "ProcessableScriptTypeList":null,
      "RunOnBuild":false
   },
   "JavaScript":{  
      "AutoMinify":true,
      "BlockCommentCompletion":true,
      "EvalTreatment":"MakeImmediateSafe",
      "GenerateSourceMaps":true,
      "GzipMinifiedFiles":false,
      "LintOnBuild":false,
      "LintOnSave":true,
      "LintResultLocation":"Message",
      "MakeMinified":true,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "RootDirectory":"/Scripts/",
      "RunOnBuild":false,
      "TermSemicolons":true
   },
   "Less":{  
      "AdjustRelativePaths":true,
      "CompileOnBuild":true,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "EnableChainCompilation":true,
      "GenerateSourceMaps":true,
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements":true,
      "ShowPreviewPane":true,
      "StrictMath":false
   },
   "LiveScript":{  
      "CompileOnBuild":false,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "GenerateSourceMaps":true,
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements":true,
      "ShowPreviewPane":true,
      "WrapClosure":true
   },
   "Markdown":{  
      "CompileOnBuild":false,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "GlobalPreviewCSSFile":null,
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "ShowPreviewPane":true
   },
   "Scss":{  
      "CompileOnBuild":true,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "EnableChainCompilation":true,
      "GenerateSourceMaps":true,
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "NumberPrecision":5,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "OutputStyle":"Expanded",
      "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements":true,
      "ShowPreviewPane":true,
      "UseRubyRuntime":false
   },
   "Sprite":{  
      "CssOutputDirectory":null,
      "IsVertical":true,
      "LessOutputDirectory":null,
      "Margin":1,
      "Optimize":true,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "RunOnBuild":false,
      "ScssOutputDirectory":null,
      "UseAbsoluteUrl":false,
      "UseFullPathForIdentifierName":true
   },
   "SweetJs":{  
      "CompileOnBuild":false,
      "CompileOnSave":true,
      "GenerateSourceMaps":true,
      "MinifyInPlace":false,
      "OutputDirectory":null,
      "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements":true,
      "ShowPreviewPane":true
   },
   "TypeScript":{  
      "LintOnBuild":false,
      "LintOnSave":true,
      "LintResultLocation":"Message",
      "ShowPreviewPane":true
   }
}
```

But in the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 I found that compilerconfig.json file is doing the minification task. But I couldn't find the configuration settings for RTLCSS framework.

Any advice, help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Also I'm not having the same issue in vs2019